# Убрать отображение атрибутов в карточке товара через SQL-запрос

Tags: sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Собственно весь вопрос в теме.
Сайт на WordPress, товары простые.
В карточке товара так:
[image: в карточке товара]

На сайте так:
[image: на сайте]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вордпресс - это блоговый движок. В нем нет магазина.

Comment: @РашенБеар у тебя лет на 10 лет устарели сведения.

Comment: Никогда не лезь в ВП SQL запросами если нет стойкого желания поломать сайт..А захочешь узнать как правлько сделать то, что тебе нужно ПОЛУЧИТЬ - создашь новый вопрос. Только не скупись на буквы.